# How are bubbles formed when a raindrop hits a flat pool of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, collision, surface-tension, bubbles

I have noticed that raindrop impact can create a bubble on the surface of the water in a hot tub (104°F) up to several centimeters in diameter that is stable for several seconds before bursting.

The sequence of events to cause the bubble to form seems both complex and dependent on a variety of forces yet they occur commonly.

Comment: this may help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/surten2.html